# 'WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj' does not exist, xcodebuild failed with code 65

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I am trying to automate real ios device with Appium on OS X Catalina.

Here is the error I get:

> Appium Doctor confirmed all required components are installed
>   successfully.  "WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj" (path
>   "/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent)successfully
>   build on **xcode (11.4.1)** & able to install/run/open the
>   "IntregrationApp" on iphone xr.

However When running "xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=udid' test" in the terminal, I am getting this error:

> xcodebuild
>   -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=udid' test"
>   "Command line invocation:
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx test    xcodebuild: error: 'WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj' does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm your path where you run this command
if you install appium through command line then verify pwd as
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent
then run above command